# C# WPF Pass selected ListView item info on button click?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to preface this with the fact that I'm only just starting to learn WPF.

I created a small window in my learning project and right now I'm trying to figure out the best way to pass a selected object information from the ListView to an event that happens on button click (in this case, Remove).

The window looks like this: [image: window]
Xaml for it is this: `

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="25" Click="Button_Click_Add"/>
    <Button Content="Edit" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,40,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="25" Click="Button_Click_Edit"/>
    <Button Content="Remove" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,100,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="25" Click="Button_Click_Remove"/>
    <Button Content="Refresh" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,70,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Height="25" Click="Button_Click_Refresh"/>
    <ListView Name="lvEmployeeList" Margin="10,10,65,10">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="Position" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Position}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

`

And the relevant info for MainWindow class: `

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        EmployeeList employeeList = EmployeeList.Load();
        lvEmployeeList.ItemsSource = employeeList.employeeRecord;

    }

    private void Button_Click_Add(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newWindow = new UserInfo();
        newWindow.Show();
    }
    private void Button_Click_Edit(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have chosen to Edit");
    }
    private void Button_Click_Remove(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Removing");
    }
    private void Button_Click_Refresh(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        EmployeeList employeeList = EmployeeList.Load();
        lvEmployeeList.ItemsSource = employeeList.employeeRecord;
        MessageBox.Show("Attempting a Refresh");
    }
}`
```

A lot of it has been placeholder functions, so I could eventually get to actually deal with the data. Each object does have a First Name, Last Name, Position, and a hidden ID behind it though.
My plan was to somehow get the object ID and use that for the remove function, but I'm unsure at how to get it from a selected object in the ListView, and then use it only on button click event for the specific button clicked.

Comment: ListView has SelectedItem property. you will need to cast it from object to concrete type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have an `Employee` class like:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use the following code to get the `Employee` Id:

```
private void Button_Click_Remove(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Employee selectedEmployee = (Employee)lvEmployeeList.SelectedItem;
    int employeeId = selectedEmployee.Id;
}
```

Comment: so I don't need to reference anything in XAML? Just reference the appropriate DataContext source in the function of the button, and good to go?

Comment: You have nothing to do with the Remove button itself or RoutedEventArg parameter in the handler. Just get the  Id of the selected Employee and then proceed with it. (You will probably delete it from the DB etc.) Note that deleting an item from the ListView does not have to be tied to a button only; you may perform this operation from a menu item or by handling the KeyPress event. So a better approach would be abstracting the Remove operation as a Command.

Comment: By the way, what are the types of EmployeeList and EmployeeList.EmployeeRecord?

Comment: EmployeeList class just has a few functions to update the actual list using the Employee. It also loads and saves it to a json file to be recalled locally, but also is already set up to take in Add, Remove, and Edit the list.